# Should start_session() be always placed at the beginning of the page and not inside an if/else clause?

Tags: php

This is the `index.php` file of my website.

```
<?php
$jump=false;
if (isset($_GET['pg']))
    if ($_GET['pg']=="signup") {
        include 'signup.php';
        $jump=true;
    }
if (!$jump)
{
    session_start(); 
    //Has the session been started? If not, 
    if ( isset($_SESSION['myusername']) ) {
        include 'main.php'; 
    }
    else {
        include 'login.php';
    }
}
?>
```

The first time you enter the site, it executes the `include 'login.php;`, and takes you to **login.php**. There, if you successfully log in, it sets `$_SESSION['myusername']="foo"` and redirects you to **index.php**, where if evaluates `if ( $_SESSION['myusername']) )` as **true** and includes **main.php**.
Well, the code works fine in local server *but* in the Remote Server, the `if ( $_SESSION['myusername']) )` evaluates **false** and it never includes **main.php**.

After some time, I've slightly changed the code, advancing the execution of `session_start()`:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if (isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
    $session = true;
else
    $session=false;

$jump=false;
if (isset($_GET['pg']))
    if ($_GET['pg']=="signup") {
        include 'signup.php';
        $jump=true;
    }

if (!$jump)
{
    //Has the session been started? If not, 
    if ( $session ) {
        include 'main.php'; 
    }
    else {
        include 'login.php';
    }
}
?>
```

So the question is: Should I always execute session_start() at the beginning of the code and avoid executing it inside (nested) if-else/while clauses? Why does it work in the local server but fails to carry on in the remote server?

Comment: You should start the session at the very top of the page, I don't understand why you need conditions to initialize that session, if you want, just create a session variable, with a value, `true` or `false` and than based on those conditions, you can simply execute the relevant code.

Comment: Hi Mr.Alien, there was a part of the code that was missed, I've added it in both versions. Anyway you're right and it's better to start the page with start_session() at the top, thanks.

Comment: @tas9 doesn't signup require sessions?

Comment: Add this 
... if (!$jump) { session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); if( ... to check whether the block is being run and also the contents of $_SESSION

Comment: Hi @frostymarvelous, in my site signup.php - form for new users -  doesn't require sessions until the new user successfully completes and sends the form, whick is checked in another .php file

Answer (score 0):

First start the session at the very top of the page and check if there is not any space before `session_start()`

or you can also do this

on start before `session_start()` write `ob_start();` and on the page end write `ob_flush();`
Use `ob_start` to buffer the output. This prevents `session_start()` from sending headers right away, and makes it wait until the end of the request.

This will help

Answer (score 0):

yes a session, session_start(); should always be starting  at the top of each page in which you are implementing the session related activities.Instead of doing it in the conditions(if,while,...)
for checking whether session exist in particular page you can use isset($_SESSION)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be on every page or it will be lost, it may depend on the server's implementation of sessions.

Please consider how much your code should be reasonably shortened:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$session = isset($_SESSION['myusername']));

$jump=isset($_GET['pg']));

if (!$jump)
{
    include ($session ? 'main.php' : 'login.php'); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $_SESSION['myusername'] ) //will return false if $_SESSION is falsey (empty string, null, 0 etc)
```

and

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['myusername']) ) //will return true as long as the key is set
```

Please do a `var_dump` on `$_SESSION` to see what it contains. I believe the error is in the logic.

`session_start()` is usually called at the start of the page to ensure that no output has already been sent. This will throw an error. I don't think this is your problem.

**Edit One**
However, you should always try to call `session_start` at the very top as this is accepted/good practice. This also ensures that any scripts included that require `$_SESSION` work without having to explicitly check for sessions.

**Edit Two**
To actually answer the title of the question, So long as you are calling `session_start` before accessing `$_SESSION` it doesn't matter where you call it. However, refer to my first edit.

Comment: Sorry, it was a transcription error, I've added the isset() function to the code